# How to run a cplex model on a network server

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I am looking for a method to run my integer program models on a machine dedicated to run CPLEX models which is on LAN. Currently, i use a command line to run the OPL model (on the same system). How can i run my OPL models on a network machine?

Thanks in advance for the help

R.Ram

Answer (score 1):

have you had a look at CPLEX Enterprise Server ?

https://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-enterprise-server/

regards